# Magento 2 indexer not working in PHP 7 (7.0.4)

Tags: magento2, reindex

### Steps to reproduce

1. Install Magento `2.0.2`. (apache 2.4.18, php 7.0.4, mariadb 10.0.24)
2. Import products from Magento 1.7.x store.
3. In Magento backend, set indexes to update on schedule.
4. Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

### Expected result

1. All indexes reindexed.

### Actual result

```
[~/www/dev]# bin/magento indexer:reindex -vv



  [InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "indexer" namespace.



Exception trace:
 () at /home/dev/public_html/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:501
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace() at /home/dev/public_html/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:535
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /home/dev/public_html/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/dev/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:49
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /home/dev/public_html/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/dev/public_html/dev/bin/magento:25
```

### Workaround

1. if i run `/opt/bin/php56/bin/php bin/magento indexer:reindex` indexing succeeds.

Comment: What does `which php` print?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with that php. Find out what your webserver is using, and use that in the command line.

Comment: both are using  php 7.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found that my cli was using a different path to php than apache.  I am using cpanel, so the cli was pointing to /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/.  After running `yum install ea-php70-php-{magento dependency}` (i.e. `yum install ea-php70-php-bcmath`, etc.) for all of the magento dependencies, I am able to use the cli without any errors.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my answer because I had same issue after uploading new module and running php bin/magento upgrade

after this I had simmillar error couldn't clean cache and run reindex.

I input again php bin/magento upgrade (only command that works)

and I found that I had bad configuration in xml file

```
Element 'global': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.  
  Line: 2
```

after I fix that issue I run again php bin/magento upgrade and all command works now.